# UWP assembly error with WebAuthenticationCoreManager

Tags: asynchronous, uwp, .net-assembly, wait, uwp-xaml

Hello I'am trying to call the WebAuthenticationCoreManager

```
private async void getAccountsAsync()
    {
        var msaProvider = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.FindAccountProviderAsync("https://login.microsoft.com", "consumers");

    }
```

And it says that I am missing an assembly reference Windows Version=255.255.255. After some search this assembly doesn't exists. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong and this throws and error? I have already tried to clean the solution, and I reinstalled the windows 10 SDK

Comment: Have you tried the [Web account management sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement)? Besides, what's the environment eg. OS Version, VS Version, Project Target you are using? With only one line of code, it's hard to say where the problem is.

Comment: I am using a UWP project. I am coding on visual studio windows 10. And i have been following this sample in order to create what i want but even with copy paste, it stills throws this error

Comment: You can just download this sample then deploy and run it to see if it has the same problem. There should be no error when using the official sample.